# Display an info table without data shape in a grid

Tags: iot, thingworx

I have a service that returns an info table with two columns: code and emirate. But for some reason, I don't want to give a data shape in the service returned data shape field, so I gave it in the code, the problem is that I can't display the returned info table in a grid, please advice me to solve this problem.

```
var params = {infoTableName: "myinfoTable"};


var result = Resources["InfoTableFunctions"].CreateInfoTable(params);

result.AddField({ name: "code", baseType: "STRING" });
result.AddField({name: "emirate", baseType: "STRING" });


var newEntry = new Object();
newEntry.emirate = "Abu Dhabi";
newEntry.code = "AUH";
result.AddRow(newEntry);

var newEntry = new Object();
newEntry.emirate = "Ajman";
newEntry.code = "AJM";
result.AddRow(newEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working now, I had a problem in the mashup connection